# How Gatsby uses .env.productionn environment file in public folder generated through gatsby build command?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I need to make sure that when I run `gatsby build` command and a public build folder is generated, the production environment variables from .env.production are not exposed to the browser when I run `gatsby serve`.

My question is - How gatsby uses the environment file in public folder ? Will someone be able to inspect these variables from the browser developer tools ? I want to make sure this doesn't happen.

Can anyone tell how gatsby uses env variables in production environment file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, those variables will be available in the client code. That's the point of using those .env files in Gatsby, so you can set "project env vars" available in the client. See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/

Comment: Okey got it. But if I am using them on the client side, they will also be exposed and can be seen in the developer tools right ? I need to avoid this security issue :/